# Nested TableView Cell getting removed in iOS 11.1 and later

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am having a table view which is having three cells. Inside that cells I have one more tableView which have n rows. It was running fine until iOS 11.0 but after update to iOS 11.1.x the inner tableview cells is getting removed from that inner tableview. Pls help me out here to fix this issue.

I m attaching a similar view for this issue for better understanding [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Wf9.png)

Comment: At least, you should show some piece of code. In my opinion, use only one table view with 3 section will resolve your problem

Comment: why would you need nested table-views in table-view-cells at the first place?

Comment: Actually I need table view inside all the cells so there is no way of using as sections. The image i shown here is just a sample for better understanding. I was not facing issue this till iOS update to 11.1. Before iOS 11.1 its working fine.